# Name and location of snippet for Menu with param in LiftWeb?

Tags: scala, lift

Sorry if this sounds stupid but I'm really new to LiftWeb and just struggling with the basic stuff:)

So I have a parametrized site map entry in Lift's bootstrap. This should be for the view page of an object of type MyItem. The URL would be like: "/myitems/UUID".

```
Menu.param [UUID]("MyItemView", "MyItemView", p=>Full(UUID.fromString(p)), p=>p.toString) / "myitems"
```

This adds the sitemap entry correctly. If I go to "/myitems/NOT_AN_UUID", it will throw the "Invalid UUID" exception as expected. But if I go to "/myitems/UUID" I get 404.

I know that I need a view and a snippet class that takes UUID as parameter in order for this to work but **I have no idea how to name these and where to place them**.

Btw, how would one new to Lift learn something like this? From the hundreds of articles and samples out there I found many to mention more complex stuff but haven't seen any to mention a basic thing like this. **Do you know any secret start-up documentation for human beings**?

> Update: To summarize in case all you see above is jibber-jabber :) **HOW DOES LIFT LOCATE TEMPLATES/VIEWS/SNIPPETS FOR PARAMETRIZED MENU ENTRIES?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the obvious answer. The template name is obtained from the path and the snippet can be whatever you want as long as you call it from the template xml.

I need to get used to all this convention over configuration :) However it would be nice for someone to tell you what is the convention.